# Why doesn't the call to the synchronized method block the object?

Tags: java

Why doesn't the call to the synchronized method block the object?
I assume that mt1.method(); should block object MyThread. But it doesn't happen.

```
class MyThread implements Runnable {
    public Thread thrd;

    public MyThread() {
        thrd = new Thread(this);
    }

    public static MyThread createAndRun() {//Test t
        MyThread mt = new MyThread();
        mt.thrd.start();
        return mt;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
// This way main thread doesn't block MyThread.
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + i + " ");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(250);
            } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
//main:0 Thread-0:0 main:1 Thread-0:1 main:2 Thread-0:2 main:3 Thread-0:3 main:4 Thread-0:4 main:5 Thread-0:5 Thread-0:6 main:6 Thread-0:7 main:7 Thread-0:8 main:8 Thread-0:9 main:9 





//        method();// if use it instead for-lopp - all works as expected. 
//main:0 main:1 main:2 main:3 main:4 main:5 main:6 main:7 main:8 main:9 Thread-0:0 Thread-0:1 Thread-0:2 Thread-0:3 Thread-0:4 Thread-0:5 Thread-0:6 Thread-0:7 Thread-0:8 Thread-0:9 
    }

    synchronized public void method() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + i + " ");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(250);
            } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThread mt1 = MyThread.createAndRun();
        mt1.method();
        try {
            mt1.thrd.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
            System.out.println(exc);
        }
    }
}
```

I assume that mt1.method(); should block object MyThread. But it doesn't happen. What don't I understand correctly?

Comment: Block what? There's only one thread here, nothing to block.

Comment: Why only one? There are main and Thread-0.

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: Right, one in addition to the main thread. Still there's nothing to block: Thread-0 is running and the main thread is waiting for it to finish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstood what `synchronized` means. It doesn't "block" an object in the sense that other methods of that object cannot run. The `run` method can totally in parallel with `method1`.

When `synchronized` methods are called, all that happens is that the monitor of `this` is acquired. After that, if some other thread *also* tries to acquire that same monitor (either by calling a `synchronized` method on the same object, or using a `synchronized` block that synchronises on that object), then that other thread will wait until the monitor is released. The monitor is released when the `synchronized` method returns or throws an exception.

In other words, if there is only ever one thread that acquires a monitor, it will not be very different from not using `synchronized` at all. This is what happens in your code - only the main thread acquires the monitor of `mt1` by calling `method1`. The `run` method doesn't acquire any monitors.

If you also call `method1` in `run`, then both the main thread and `mt1` will try to acquire the monitor. One of them will get it, and the other will have to wait until the monitor is released.

Comment: I read your answer without result, then read Java The Complete Reference, and now I understand that your answer is correct. There is no difference between statements object.syncMethod() and synchronized (object) { object.nonSyncMethod() } because they both do the same thing - they just say "thread, try to get access to the monitor of this object". If thread call nonSyncMethod without sync block - it's not problem, because this thread doesn't try to control monitor. Am I correct? If yes - thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

When you synchronize methods in an object, you are telling the JVM to only allow one execution of all `synchronized` methods at a time. In your code, you are running MyThread#method() on the primary thread. While the method is executing, all other accesses to that singular method are blocked.

However, the synchronization of a method will only block *synchronized methods* in the object, not the object itself. If you want to block an entire object, you will have to use a synchronized block on that object.

If you prefer to block the entire object of MyThread, here is how you would do that:

```java
class MyThread implements Runnable {
    public Thread thrd;

    public MyThread() {
        thrd = new Thread(this);
    }

    public static MyThread createAndRun() {
        MyThread mt = new MyThread();
        mt.thrd.start();
        return mt;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + i + " ");

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(250);
                } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void method() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + i + " ");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(250);
            } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThread mt1 = MyThread.createAndRun();
        synchronized (mt1) {
            mt1.method();
        }
        try {
            mt1.thrd.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
            System.out.println(exc);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the following output:

```
main:0 main:1 main:2 main:3 main:4 main:5 main:6 main:7 main:8 main:9 Thread-0:0 Thread-0:1 Thread-0:2 Thread-0:3 Thread-0:4 Thread-0:5 Thread-0:6 Thread-0:7 Thread-0:8 Thread-0:9
```

Comment: "only allow a singular execution of that method on one thread at a time" - that's not correct. It only allows execution of *any* synchronized method on that object on one thread at a time. If there are multiple synchronized methods, they're all synchronized against the same object.

Comment: Wow I didn't know that. Learn something new every day.